# Navigation between Full screen view and Master detail view in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I have a requirement. the requirement is here is a one SAPUI5 application.
Application contains two views,
1. Initial View is Full Screen view
2. Second view is Master Detail view

am stuck at Navigation between Full screen view and Master detail view.
Even am not getting any error to share with you. after click on action/event(Button) the screen is dumb, that's it no response from the view.

Please give a suggestions, am waiting for your valuable reply.

Regards,
Kiran.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation from Full-Screen View to Master-Detail View SAPUI5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407437/navigation-from-full-screen-view-to-master-detail-view-sapui5)

Comment: Btw. Fiori UX Guidelines [explicitly says](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/full-screen/) "Avoid switching between full and split-screen layouts within an app."

Answer (score -1):

Create a project in which includes **Master Detail Template** View files & **FullScreen templates** files i.e.

1. App.view.xml & App.Controller.js
2. Master.view.xml & Master.controller.js
3. Details.view.xml & Details.controller.js
4. S1.view.xml & S1.controller.js

**S1.view.xml**

```js
<Button text="click to splite App" press="onPressSplite"/>
```

**S1.controller.js**

```js
 onPressSplite : function(oEvent) {      
  var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent
  .getRouterFor(this);
  oRouter.navTo("main", {});
 },
 getEventBus : function() {
   return sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
 },
 getRouter : function() {
   return sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
 }
```

After creating these views then just define the routing of pages in Component.js

```js
 routing : {
  config : {
   routerClass : Application_Name.MyRouter,
   viewType : "XML",
   viewPath : "Application_Name.view",
   targetAggregation : "pages",
   clearTarget : false
  },
  routes : [{
   pattern : "",
   name : "S1",
   view : "S1",
   targetControl : "masterView",
  },{
   pattern : "App",
   name : "app",
   view : "App",
   targetControl : "masterView",
   subroutes : [{
    pattern : "master",
    name : "main",
    view : "Master",
    targetAggregation : "masterPages",
    targetControl : "idAppControl",
    subroutes : [{
     pattern : "detail/{key}",
     name : "Detail",
     view : "Detail",
     targetAggregation : "detailPages",
    }]
   }]
  }]
 }
```

**Don't forget add MyRouter.js file**

Comment: How can we do it vise versa? I mean from a Master-Detail view to a full screen and then go back to Master-Detail. I mean showing the Master-Detail first and full screen page as an sub view.