# Navigation from Full-Screen View to Master-Detail View SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

### Dear Gurus,

As my title, I'm tryig to create an App which contains a Full-screen Menu page with some tiles, and when user presses on one, it navigate to another Master-Detail page. My problem is I can't show the detail page. My code works as below:

`manifest.json`:

```
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "viewPath": "WYTH.view",
            "controlId": "rootApp",
            "controlAggregation": "pages"
        },
        "routes": [{
            "pattern": "menu",
            "name": "menu",
            "view": "Menu",
            "targetControl": "rootApp",
            "targetAggregation": "pages"
        }, {
            "pattern": "zwm01",
            "name": "zwm01",
            "view": "ZWM01Root",
            "targetControl": "rootApp",
            "targetAggregation": "pages",
            "subroutes": [{
                "pattern": "zwm01/",
                "name": "zwm01master",
                "view": "ZWM01Master",
                "targetControl": "ZWM01",
                "targetAggregation": "masterPages",
                "subroutes": [{
                    "pattern": "zwm01/",
                    "name": "zwm01detail",
                    "view": "ZWM01Detail",
                    "targetControl": "ZWM01",
                    "targetAggregation": "detailPages"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },
```

I managed to show the menu view with this. When I click on 1 tile, it fires the function below:

```
navZWM01: function() {
        this.getRouter().navTo("zwm01", false); 
    },
```

In result, it doesn't show the detailpage, but the masterpage
[image]

Any suggestions?

Best regards

Comment: Once you navigate to the master, you will have to perform a second navigation to the detail on some event.

Comment: yeah. I'm currently using that approach. On mobile view where 1 view is shown up at  time, it isn't required to load both master and detail views. So I made an `if` at `onAfterRendering` listener to check whether the device is not a phone, it will perform a second navigation to the detail view as u mentioned. Thank you a lot sir.

Comment: @T.NQ: Did you figure it out what could be the mistake? If possible could you share the solution here which will be helpful to others.

Comment: Sorry I gave up that approach. I use full-screen instead. So sorry there's nothing I can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) To launch full screen app i am using the routing as follows. Here Iam loading App Container wiith the help of rootView

```
routes : [
  {
    pattern : "",
    name : "_full1",
    targetAggregation: "pages",
    target : "monitorOperations"
   }
 ],

"targets": {
     "monitorOperations" : {
                "viewName": "Full1", 
                "viewLevel": 1, 
                "viewId": "_Full1Id", 
                "controlId": "idAppControl",
                "controlAggregation": "pages" 
       },
}
```

2) To Load master detail template iam using the routing as follows. Here iam loading the splitApp container with the help of rootView

```
routes : [
             { 
               "pattern": "", 
                "name": "master", 
                "target": ["detail", "master"] 
             }, 
             { 
               "pattern": "detail/{detailId}", 
                "name": "detail",
                "target": ["master", "detail"] 
            } 
           ],
"targets": { 
           "master": {
                        "viewName": "Master", 
                        "viewLevel": 1, 
                         "viewId": "master", 
                         "controlId": "idAppControl",
                        "controlAggregation": "masterPages" 
                       }, 
            "detail": {
                     "viewName": "Detail", 
                      "viewId": "detail",
                      "controlId": "idAppControl",
                      "controlAggregation": "detailPages", 
                      "viewLevel": 2 
                    }, 
          "notFound": {
                 "viewName": "NotFound", 
                  "viewId": "notFound", 
                  "viewLevel": 3 
            } 
        }
```

Combine both, in such a way that the full screen (app container) is loaded first, when user clicks on button or selects any Tile/Item in the full screen then load the second page (split container with master and detail)

```
routing: {
    config : {
            routerClass : MyRouter,
            viewType : "XML",
            viewPath : "org.edu.ui.views",
            targetAggregation : "detailPages",
            clearTarget : false
             },
         routes : [
                {
                    pattern : "",
                     name : "_full1",
                    arget   : "monitorOperations"
                },
                {
                    pattern : "manageOperations",
                    name : "_full2",
                    target  : ["SplitAppContainer","detail", "master"]
                },
                {  
                                "pattern": "detail/{product}",  
                                "name": "detail",
                                "target": ["master", "detail"]  
                         },
                {  
                                "pattern": "manageOperations1",  
                                "name": "master",  
                                "target": ["detail", "master"]  
                            }
                ],

    "targets": {
            "monitorOperations" : {
                    "viewName": "Full1",  
                                         "viewLevel": 1,  
                                         "viewId": "_Full1Id",  
                                         "controlId": "idAppControl",
                                         "controlAggregation": "pages" 
                    },
            "SplitAppContainer" : {
                    "viewId": "_Full2Id",  
                    "viewName": "Full2",  
                                        "viewLevel": 1,  
                                        "controlId": "idAppControl",
                                        "controlAggregation": "pages"
                    },
            "master": {
                    "parent" : "SplitAppContainer",
                                        "viewName": "Master1",  
                                        "viewLevel": 2,  
                                        "viewId": "master",  
                                        "controlId": "idSplitContainerControl",
                                        "controlAggregation": "masterPages"  
                                       },  
                    "detail": {
                                     "parent" : "SplitAppContainer",
                                     "viewName": "Detail",  
                                     "viewId": "detail",
                                     "controlId": "idSplitContainerControl",
                                     "controlAggregation": "detailPages", 
                                     "viewLevel": 3  
                                },  
                    "notFound": {
                                 "viewName": "NotFound",  
                                 "viewId": "notFound",  
                                 "viewLevel": 3  
                             } 
                      } 
      }
```

I used this in my implementation, Thanks to Saran Kumar, Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you a lot sir. Now I almost finish the app so I will certainly test your approach and respond as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create two routes and tow targets, one for Master and one for Details. Each target is binded to a View, as defined in the viewName property of your targets. Set the `target` property of both routes to navigate to both targets.

```
"routes": [
    {
      "pattern": "",
      "name": "master",
      "target": ["object", "master"]
    },
    {
      "pattern": "Objects/{objectId}",
      "name": "object",
      "target": ["master", "object"]
    }
  ],
  "targets": {
    "master": {
      "viewName": "Master",
      "viewLevel": 1,
      "viewId": "master",
      "controlAggregation": "masterPages"
    },
    "object": {
      "viewName": "Detail",
      "viewId": "detail",
      "viewLevel": 2
    }
```

Then when you navigate from the tile click, both targets are matched. If you pass parameters to your details view, catch the "routeMatched" or the "patternMatched" events of the Router object and change the "detail" view context with `bindElement()`

This is very detailed in the demokit: [Master-Detail Navigation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/89de2f43b91d470daa8121a0b4ba35cc.html)

Comment: Sorry sir but it seems u didn't answer my question. I've managed to navigate between Master-Detail views within a SplitApp control. What I want to achieve now is to navigate between `<App>` and `<SplitApp>` (different `controlId`). Anw, thank you for your help.

Comment: I think there is no way to change the controlId associated to the router. As an idea:
1. You can define a High-level container to manage the router navigation, eg. sap.m.App. As per your manifest with ID "rootApp".
2. Inside "rootApp" control you can embbed whatever you want in full screen mode (e.g another sap.m.App or sap.m.SplitApp).
 - 2.1 define "fullScreen" target to load your FullScreen view into "rootApp" control
 - 2.2 define "zwm01" pattern which loads your SplitApp View into "rootApp". Then catch the patternMatched event for "zwm01" and change Master and Detail manually

Comment: Another idea is to do the first navigation manually and configure the router for sap.m.SplitApp.
E.g. set first a NavContainer with your tiles. Use to() function when you click them to navigate to the page with the SplitApp (already handled by the router).
This way, your SplitApp will be created at the begining but it will remain invisible until you use the to() function. Then it will appear and it will show the MasterDetail depending on your hash.
If the tiles navigate to different section of your splitApp, change the hash when clicking a tile.
Never tried this, but I think it should work